# Report: Create report on accounts that are created via lead process

Tags: reporting, lead-conversion

I would like to create a report which shows me how many of my accounts were created via the lead conversion process.

I know that there is a field on the lead "`Converted Account`", however, if the account already existed when leads were converted, will this field be filled in as well? Are there any other indicators I could use?

[edit]
I tried creating a Lead with converted information, however I don't seem to have access to any fields of the Accounts that were created. Only Contacts and Opportunities (see screenshot).
[image]

Tia, Lily.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you obtain the Accounts that were created from a Lead conversation all you need to do is got to:

1. Reports->
2. New Report ->
3. Open the "Leads" reports->
4. Select Leads with coverted lead information.
5. Create

For your logic use the filter

> Converted equals true

Make sure that the `Company/Account` is on you report. 
By doing this you can get a report with the "Converted" leads and the accounts that were also converted in that process.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this for ongoing lead conversions is to add a custom field on Lead called `isConvertedToNew Account__c`. Default is false (unchecked). Populate this to true on lead conversion event using workflow/process builder.  Then in the Lead field mappings, map this field to an Account field `WasCreatedByLeadConversion__c`

You can retrospectively update your Accounts by querying converted leads and getting the `convertedAccountId`